# Tick marks and labels not appearing on D3.js graph

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js, time

I am attempting to generate a graph that has an x-axis with tick marks every month in a range.

I am using TypeScript React with Vite as the build tool.

The issue I am having is that the tick marks do not appear on the graph when displayed on the HTML.

The code I am using is below. For reference, I am following the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5bp02-CRAc that was done in JS

You can also run the code here: https://codepen.io/michaelnicol/pen/YzgqPJG?editors=1111

```
export const App = () => {
  const data = useMemo(() => {
    // The data for the x-axis range
    return [
      new Date("2022-01-01"),
      new Date("2022-02-01"),
      new Date("2022-03-01"),
      new Date("2022-04-01"),
      new Date("2022-05-01")
    ]
  }, [])
  const svgRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement>(null);
  const width = 500
  const height = 500
  useEffect(() => {
    if (svgRef.current) {
      const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
      // Remove all SVG
      svg.selectAll("*").remove();
      // Generate the width and domain of the x and y axis.
      // The x-axis will be 500 px wide with a domain of lowest to highest date.
      const xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]).domain(d3.extent(data) as [Date, Date]);
      // yScale will be a linear scale from 0 to 500 pixels.
      const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0])
      // Create the x-axis
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`) // Move x-axis to bottom of graph
        .call(
          d3.axisBottom(xScale) // Generate an axis to place tick marks on.
            .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1)) // The ticks will be spaced out every month
            .tickFormat((d, i) => { // The text for each tick will be the month name
              if (d instanceof Date) {
                return d3.timeFormat("%B")(d) as string
              } else {
                return "" + d
              }
            }))
      // Generate the y-axis, no ticks.
      svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
    }
  }, [data])

  return (
    <>
      {<svg
        ref={svgRef}
        width={width}
        height={height}
      />}
    </>
  )
}
```

This results in an empty x and y axis, as seen below.
[image]

Comment: could you put your code in snippet, it will be easier to help you with a functional sample

Comment: https://codepen.io/michaelnicol/pen/YzgqPJG?editors=1111